# Editor Window Show method is not working properly

Tags: unity, c#

[Documentation says](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.Show.html) that `EditorWindow.Show` show the EditorWindow.

I have two classes:

```
public class WindowOne : EditorWindow {

    public static WindowOne windowOneInstance;

    [MenuItem("Window/Open Window One")]
    public static void Init() {
        windowOneInstance = GetWindow<WindowOne>(false, "Window One", true);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class WindowTwo : EditorWindow {

    public static WindowTwo windowTwoInstance;
    public static WindowOne windowOneInstance;

    [MenuItem("Window/Open Window Two")]
    public static void Init() {
        windowTwoInstance = GetWindow<WindowTwo>(false, "Window Two", true);
        windowOneInstance = WindowOne.windowOneInstance;
    }

    public void OnGUI() {
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 0, 200, 50), new GUIContent("show window one"))) {
            windowOneInstance.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

In menu I click `Open Window One`, then `Open Window Two`, then I close the first window

[image]

Now if I click a `Button` on `WindowTwo` it doesn't show me `WindowOne`. Or at least it shows one-pixel of window that I cannot move or resize or do something else.

[image]

If I use `GetWindow(typeof (WindowOne));` instead of  `.Show()` - it shows the window, but I'm not sure that it shows the same instance I created before, because `instanceID` of that window will be different.

---

Why `Show` method works so strange? Am I doing something wrong? And  what should I do to show the same instance of closed (temporarily hidden) window?

*Unity* version - 5.6.0p4

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want your `WindowOne`s to be the same instance?

Comment: @S.TarıkÇetin yes. I create a window -  a toolbox for another window that can be hidden/shown in any time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.OnDestroy.html):

> OnDestroy is called when the EditorWindow is closed.

It seems like Unity destroys the instance of the editor window when you close it.

After the instance is destroyed, when you call the `Show()` method, it fails to find the instance so it probably falls down to a default window, which is what you are referring to as *one-pixel of window*.

But as you can see [here in the documentation of `GetWindow()` method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.GetWindow.html):

> Returns the first EditorWindow of type t which is currently on the
>   screen.
>
> **If there is none, creates and shows new window and returns the
>   instance of it.**

`GetWindow()` method creates a new instance for you if there is no instance available. So you are getting a fresh instance when you call `GetWindow()` after closing the existing instance.

---

About your concerns on the windows being the same instance:

If your purpose is the persistence of data between editor windows, you can achieve so using serialization or a data holder class.

---

**Edit:**

After some research, I have come to the conclusion that there is no way to "hide" an editor window rather than "closing" it.

There is no way to prevent an editor window from receiving input, so somehow making it invisible and allowing input to go through is not possible either.

Comment: `It seems like Unity destroys the instance of the editor window when you close it` - Strange. It seems so.. Then why `Show` method do not throw a null reference exception >_< ......is there a way just hide a window and show it any time?

Comment: It is strange to me to use `Show` method and do not use/find `Hide` but anyway I will be save my data OnDisable window  and restore it OnEnable. Thanks.